# Eclipse:File >Team> Share Project button is disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, project

[What do I need to install to activate this button Share Project in Eclipse?I need to transfer the project to GitHub.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liuMu.png)

Comment: Do it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

**Right-click** the **project folder** instead of a file/folder inside the project.